# has_many :through model names, controller and attributes best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, rails-activerecord

**Disclaimer:** I really spent time thinking about names of models and variables. If you also do, this question is for you.

I have a Rails project which contains two models: `User` and `Project`.

They are connected by the model `ProjectsUser`, which is a connection model in a many-to-many relationship. This model also holds the `role` of a user in the given project, along with other attributes such as `tier` and `departments`. So this is a `has_many :through` relationship.

Given this scenario, here is everything that always bothered me on all my rails projects since I started developing on it:

1. **Should I use a `ProjectsUserController` or better add the relevant actions on `UserController` and `ProjectController`**? At some point, I want to assign users to a project, or even changing the role of a user in a given project. Is it a better practice to leave those actions on the connection controller, or use the model controllers?
2. **Should I write a method to get the role of a user for a given project?** This is basically if I should have a method `User#role_for(project)` or not. Since this method basically is getting the information from the `projects_user` object it could make more sense to always let this explicity on the code, since most of the times I'll have the `project` and the `user`, but not the `projects_user`. Is this line of thinking correct, or maybe the problem is that I'm should have more `project_user` on my code than I really do? Are there good caveats for this?
3. **Should I try to rename my table to a non-standard name if it is not obvious?** Ok, I got that if I have the models `User` and `NewsSite` I should use `has_many :subscriptions`, but the thing is that naming those models in real life cases are usually harder, by my experience. When the name ends up not being that obvious (for exemple, in my case, maybe `project_participation` as @wonderingtomato suggested) is for the best, or in those cases it is better to fall back to the `ProjectsUser` approach?

One extra cookie for pointing beautiful open source Rails code, or by book indications that might help with my kind of questions.

Comment: `projects_users` is the conventional table name for a Rails many-to-many relationship that would relate your models using the [has and belongs to many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) feature.  I would stick with it for consistency.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Even using `has_many through:` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: You have to be explicit with the join model using `has_many through:` so that join model must have a certain table name. The only table name convention I know for join models is the HABTM one. However there's no technical advantage to use that convention to my knowledge unless you find later that you no longer need the `role` field in the join model and could switch to HABTM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a specific controller. Even if now the interaction sounds simple, you can't know if in the future you'll need to add more advanced features.
I've been handling these kind of relationships in several projects, and using a controller for the join model has always paid off.

You can structure it this way, for example:

- `index` should expect a `params[:project_id]`, so that you can display only the index of users for a specific project.
- `create` is where you add new users, that is where you create new join models.
- `update` is to modify a value on an existing join model, for example when you want to update the role of a user in a project.
- `destroy` is where you remove users from the project, that is where you delete the corresponding join models.
- You might not need a `show` and `edit` actions, if you decide to manage everything in the `index` view.

Also, I'd suggest to choose a different name. Rails relies heavily on naming conventions, and `projects_users` is the default name for the **join_table** you would use with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. In theory you **can** use it for an independent model (and a `has_many through:`), but it's not immediately clear and you might break something. In addiction, it will confuse the hell out of any new programmer that could join the project in the future (personal experience).

What about calling the model something like `project_participation`?

If you haven't built a lot of functionality yet, and don't have yet that table in production, changing it now will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

### update

1) I stand by what I said earlier: your *join model* is a full fledged record, it holds state, can be fetched, modified (by the user) and destroyed.
A dedicated controller is the way to go. Also, this controller should handle all the operations that modify the *join model*, that is that alter its properties.

2) You can define `User#role_for(project)`, just remember that it should properly handle the situation where the `user` is not participating to the `project`.

You can also make it explicit with something like:

```
@user.project_participations.where(project_id: @project.id).first.try(:role)
# or...
ProjectParticipation.find_by(project_id: @project.id, user_id: @user.id).try(:role)
```

But I'd say that encapsulating this logic in a method (on one of the two models) would be better.

3) You are already using a *non standard* name for your table. What I mean is that it's the default name for a different kind of association (`has_and_belongs_to_many`), not the one you are using (`has_many through:`).
Ask yourself this: is the table backing an actual model? If yes, that model represents *something* in the real world, and thus should have an appropriate name. If, on the other hand, the table is **not** backing a model (e.g. it's a join table), then you should combine the names of the tables (models) it's joining.

Comment: I updated the question greatly in case you want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, REST doesn't always have to map directly to DB records. A conceptual resource here is the association of Projects to Users. Implementation would be different depending on your persistence layer, but a RESTful API would be standard.

Convention over Configuration in Rails is a great helper, but it isn't necessarily applicable to every case 100% of the way through the stack. There doesn't need to be a 1-to-1 mapping between controllers, models, and their respective names. At the app-level, particularly, I want my routes/controllers to represent the public view of the API, not the internal implementation details of the persistence and domain layers.

You might have a `UserProjectsController` which you can perform CRUD on to add/remove project associations to users, and it will do the appropriate record manipulation without being overly bound to the DB implementation. Note the naming, where the route might be `/user/:id/projects`, so it's clear you are manipulating not Users or Projects, but their associations.

Answer (score 1):

I think thinking about this sort of thing (both before and after the fact) is what leads to better designs.

1. I too start with the model and think about the application structurally. The next step in my oppinion is to build the user interface to make sense based on what makes it easy and useful for the user (spending more effort on things that matter more). So if it makes sense for the user to separately edit the ProjectsUser objects then the ProjectsUsersController is the way to go. More likely editing the join model objects as part of the Project (or User depending on the structure of you app) will be a better fit for the user. In that case using a nested form and editing via the controller (and model) that's the main model referenced by the form is better. The controller really lives to serve the UI, so decisions about it should be dependent on the UI.
2. Yes, if it makes your code simpler or more readable. If you use role more than once I suspect it will.
3. I would actually name that model something like Member, or ProjectMember (or Membership). It defines a relationship between a user and a project, so its name should reflect what relationship that is. In the occasions where such a name is too unwieldly or too hard to define then falling back to something like ProjectUser is reasonable (but not ProjectsUser). But I definitely like finding a more meaningful name when possible.